# Выбор Н или НН, а также формы написания НЕ в кратких прилагательных

Tags: орфография, частица-не, нн

Помогите, пожалуйста, выбрать Н или НН и слитное или раздельное написание НЕ для кратких прилагательных в приведенном предложении:

**Встреча не/гада(н)на, не/проше(н)на.**

Comment: Вопрос оказался таким "легким", что пришлось его полностью править. Хотелось бы услышать и другие ответы.

Comment: Возможны варианты, значит. Просто раздельно с НЕ сочетания именно в этом случае мне казались странными: не прошена, не гадана) Видимо, из-за того, что редко употребляются прошеный и гаданый

Comment: Да, вы правы, я с вами согласна. Спасибо за интересный вопрос.

Comment: А вам - за ответ)

Comment: Алана, мне тоже понравился вопрос (плюсик давно поставил). Хочу обратить Ваше внимание на то, что на этом сайте, кроме благодарности в комментариях, принято отмечать все полезные ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а тот, что решил проблему, – еще и галочкой (как принятый).

Comment: Учту ваше пожелание 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе возможны два варианта письма:

(1) ***Встреча негаданна, непрошена.*** (2) ***Встреча не гадана, не прошена.***

Оба варианта можно объяснить, они соответствуют правилам и словарям.  Но во втором варианте более красивая графика, этого нельзя не учитывать.

Что выбрать? Вероятно,  всё-таки форму (2), но при этом надо быть готовым к тому, чтобы объяснить свой выбор.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1. По правилам Розенталя, краткие прилагательные **сохраняют** форму написания полных прилагательных,  наличие НЕ также **не влияет** на форму письма. В частности, в кратких прилагательных пишется Н или НН, выбор НЕ делается по общим правилам для полных и кратких форм.

В данном случае написание НЕ выбирается по общему значению: НЕ пишется **слитно** в утвердительной форме и **раздельно** в отрицательной форме.

2. Из толкового словаря на Грамоте.ру:

НЕПРОШЕНЫЙ, 1. Явившийся без приглашения; незваный. Н. гость, посетитель. 2. Ненужный, нежелательный для кого-л. Н-ое внимание, сочувствие.  НЕГАДАННЫЙ,  Разг. Неожиданный, непредвиденный. Н. подарок. Н-ое известие.

3. Из орфографического словаря на Грамоте.ру:
   *негаданный*, прил.,  *непрошеный*, прил. (непрошеный гость),  *прошеный,* прил. *гаданый*, прил.

Формы ***прошеный*** и ***гаданый*** встречаются редко, но всё же встречаются, например:

А когда начало смеркаться, схватила рыбную корзину и, ***не звана, не прошена***, отправилась на нижнюю заводь. [М. Л. Халфина. (1978)] Желанный, **прошеный и моленый**, он не только отца и мать, но и всех обрадовал своим появлением на белый свет. [С. Т. Аксаков) (1856)]

4. Следовательно, в краткой форме возможен выбор: (1) ***негаданна*** и ***не гадана***;  (2) ***непрошена*** и ***не прошена***.

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ**

Правила Розенталя
http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77
9. С краткими формами прилагательных частица НЕ пишется в основном так же, как с полными: 1) слитно при отсутствии противопоставления: комната невысока; вопрос непонятен; недействительна сделка в нарушение закона; Залив неглубок, но удобен для плавания на моторном катере; 2) раздельно при наличии противопоставления: роман не интересен, а скучен.

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62
7. В кратких формах страдательных причастий пишется одно Н. В кратких отглагольных прилагательных (как и в отыменных) сохраняется написание НН.